How to configure Emacs to use quail for org-mode and other modes?
I recently became acquainted with the quail input method for entering mathematical symbols and really liked it. However, this method works only when I use the agda2-mode, in which I can enter a key sequence such as \GG to the get Unicode symbols (Γ) (as far as I understand). I am not familiar with quail, and I am wondering whether this works for other modes as well. If so,
how can one configure init.el to make the same quail functions (as in agda2-mode) to work for other modes such as org-mode and text-mode?
Does quail conflict with existing methods for inputting LaTeX equations in org-mode (or do they work together nicely)?

It looks like that package is providing a custom "Agda" input method, so you'll just need to (require 'agda-input) and then you can choose "Agda" just like any other input method.
Refer to the manual for more information:
C-hig (emacs)Select Input Method


Does quail conflict with existing methods for inputting LaTeX equations in org-mode (or do they work together nicely)?

AFAIK, all input methods in Emacs are quail-based.
So if those "existing methods" are in fact input methods, you would be able to switch between them freely, but I believe you could only have one active at any given time.
Note that you can set default-transient-input-method independently of default-input-method.  If you have exactly two input methods of interest, and mostly only want occasional single characters from one of them, then that would seem to be a convenient option.
